# How would we do this hard 2 column proof involving a circle?

Tags: geometry

I need help with this proof that I have found online.

I have so far used the theorem the inscribed angle and angle-angle similarity theorem,

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How did it fail?  What theorems do you know that can be used to conclude that two triangles are similar?  What do you know about angles inscribed in circles?

Comment: You have two right-angle triangles with one common angle.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to what you are missing. While we have to make guesses as to what exactly you mean by "theorem the inscribed angle" and "angle-angle similarity theorem", the most obvious choices, along with tangents are perpendicular to radii, are all that is necessary to prove this result.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, I would expect a definition of "2 column proof".